# When browser back button is used, the headers in my app don't change

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, kendo-ui

In my angularjs app when I use the browser's back button to navigate to the previous page. The headers of my app don't switch back.

I haven't handled this problem because I assumed this would be catered when the page loads.

The app is large so there isn't any specific code. The problem is throughout the app.

I expect the headers to change back to the previous page's regardless of if I am navigating using in app buttons or through the browser's back button.

Comment: by headers you mean a rendered component inside of your app or actual request headers like e.g. `content-type` or cookies

Comment: Rendered component inside the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind it to the data in controller and  change it using your code

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="en"/>

<!-- other stuff -->


<!-- dynamic data -->
<meta name="description" content="{{htmlDescription}}">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" ng-href="{{htmlFavIcon}}"/>
<title ng-bind="htmlTitle"></title>
```

when you hit back button from ctrlB, previous controller (let's call it ctrlA) logic should be fired. Inside ctrlA :

```
$rootScope.htmlTitle = ' title of screen A';

$rootScope.htmlDescription = ' html desc of screen A';
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate.